# Spigot API - Getting multiple strings from a player

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to make it so when you click a sign it says "Enter your tag", then you enter your tag, then it says "Enter your bracket color", then you enter your bracket color, then enter your name color, then chat color. It works, but sometimes the bracket color sets the name color, and once i make the chat color it will probably do that. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
ArrayList<Player>  input = new ArrayList<Player>();
@EventHandler
public void onChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent event){
    Player p = event.getPlayer();
    if(input.contains(p)){
        String tag = event.getMessage();
        event.setCancelled(true);
        if(tag.equals("clear")){
            UUID playerid = p.getUniqueId();
            FileConfiguration cfg = getTagsConfig();
            cfg.set("tags." + playerid + ".tag", null);
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Tag Cleared!");
        }
        else{
            UUID playerid = p.getUniqueId();
            FileConfiguration cfg = getTagsConfig();
            cfg.set("tags." + playerid + ".tag", tag);
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Your prefix is now " + tag);
        }
        saveTagsFile();
        input.remove(p);
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Enter a bracket color (lowercase)");
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "a" + ChatColor.AQUA + "b" + ChatColor.RED + "c" + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "d" + ChatColor.YELLOW + "e" + ChatColor.WHITE + "f" + ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + "1" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "2" + ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + "3" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "4" + ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "5" + ChatColor.GOLD + "6" + ChatColor.GRAY + "7" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "8" + ChatColor.BLUE + "9" + ChatColor.BLACK + "0");
        input2.add(p);
    }
}
ArrayList<Player> input2 = new ArrayList<Player>();
@EventHandler
public void onChat2(AsyncPlayerChatEvent event){
    Player p = event.getPlayer();
    if(input2.contains(p)){
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Enter a bracket color (lowercase)");
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "a" + ChatColor.AQUA + "b" + ChatColor.RED + "c" + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "d" + ChatColor.YELLOW + "e" + ChatColor.WHITE + "f" + ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + "1" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "2" + ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + "3" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "4" + ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "5" + ChatColor.GOLD + "6" + ChatColor.GRAY + "7" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "8" + ChatColor.BLUE + "9" + ChatColor.BLACK + "0");
        String brackets = event.getMessage();
        event.setCancelled(true);
        if(brackets.equals("a")||brackets.equals("b")||brackets.equals("c")||brackets.equals("d")||brackets.equals("e")||brackets.equals("f")||brackets.equals("1")||brackets.equals("2")||brackets.equals("3")||brackets.equals("4")||brackets.equals("5")||brackets.equals("6")||brackets.equals("7")||brackets.equals("8")||brackets.equals("9")||brackets.equals("0")){
            UUID playerid = p.getUniqueId();
            FileConfiguration cfg = getTagsConfig();
            cfg.set("tags." + playerid + ".brackets", brackets);
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Bracket color set to: " + "" + brackets);
        }
        else{
            return;     
        }
        saveTagsFile();
        input2.remove(p);
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Enter a name color (lowercase)");
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "a" + ChatColor.AQUA + "b" + ChatColor.RED + "c" + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "d" + ChatColor.YELLOW + "e" + ChatColor.WHITE + "f" + ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + "1" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "2" + ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + "3" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "4" + ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "5" + ChatColor.GOLD + "6" + ChatColor.GRAY + "7" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "8" + ChatColor.BLUE + "9");
        input3.add(p);
    }
}
ArrayList<Player> input3 = new ArrayList<Player>();
@EventHandler
public void onChat3(AsyncPlayerChatEvent event){
    Player p = event.getPlayer();
    if(input3.contains(p)){
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Enter a name color (lowercase)");
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "a" + ChatColor.AQUA + "b" + ChatColor.RED + "c" + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "d" + ChatColor.YELLOW + "e" + ChatColor.WHITE + "f" + ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + "1" + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "2" + ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + "3" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "4" + ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "5" + ChatColor.GOLD + "6" + ChatColor.GRAY + "7" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "8" + ChatColor.BLUE + "9");
        String name = event.getMessage();
        event.setCancelled(true);
        if(name.equals("a")||name.equals("b")||name.equals("c")||name.equals("d")||name.equals("e")||name.equals("f")||name.equals("1")||name.equals("2")||name.equals("3")||name.equals("4")||name.equals("5")||name.equals("6")||name.equals("7")||name.equals("8")||name.equals("9")){
            UUID playerid = p.getUniqueId();
            FileConfiguration cfg = getTagsConfig();
            cfg.set("tags." + playerid + ".name", name);
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Name color set to: " + "" + name);
        }
        else{
            return;     
        }
        saveTagsFile();
        input3.remove(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ecoeka here is a screenshot of what happens ingame

Comment: You are sending the second and third message twice. Are you sure that is not the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I certainly understand what you are trying to accomplish and your concepts of "queues" (i.e.
`input`,`input2`, etc.) is solid. However, actual implementation of the control make some
assumptions that do not necessarily hold true.

**Duplicate prompts**
As MrDarkLynx already pointed out, you are sending double prompts. Fortunately, that is just
a cosmetic issue.

**Event Listener Call Order**
Given that your event handlers all have the same event priority (NORMAL) you are not guaranteed
that they are called in the order of their definition (i.e. `onChat()` → `onChat2()`
→ `onChat3()`).

`HandlerList` which maintains an event's listeners does use arrays and `ArrayList`s, but
`SimplePluginManager`'s listener registration does not. The order of your events may change
between server restarts. The calling order will remain consistent during a server session,
unless they are unregistered and re-registered with the plugin manager.

**Cancelling Events**
Cancelling an event does not prevent your or other plugin's event handlers from processing the
event. Cancelling only marks an event as cancelled. You must either check for it explicitly

```
if ( event.isCancelled() )
    return;
```

or specify it in your event annotation

```
@EventHandler( ignoreCancelled=true )
```

## DIY Solution

Essentially what you are trying to implement is a *state machine* that manages a conversation
between your plugin and a player during which the player is prompted for answers until the task
is completed or cancelled.

The DIY approach is to implement an actual state machine whose
execution is triggered whenever a player causes certain events to happen. I refer to this
solution as DIY, because there is a better solution, which I will present further below.

The code below is a *mock-up* of your event handlers into a singular state machine that is
capable of maintaining states for multiple players. Keep in mind that while this code works,
it is purely for educational and demonstration purposes. Use at your own risk.

```
public class DyiTagController implements Listener {
    private static final String VALID_COLOR_PAT = "^[a-f0-9]$";

    /** Valid controller states*/
    private enum TagState {
        PREFIX, BRACKET, NAME, DONE, ERR
    };

    /** Registry of current player sessions */
    private final Map<Player, PlayerSession> sessions = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * Constructs a DyiTagController and self-registers itself as event listener
     * 
     * @param plugin main plugin reference
     */
    public DyiTagController( JavaPlugin plugin ) {
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents( this, plugin );
    }

    /**
     * Only process un-cancelled chat events. If player has an active state, handle chat
     * message as input to be further validated; otherwise, ignore it.
     * 
     * @param event chat event record
     */
    @EventHandler( ignoreCancelled = true )
    public void onPlayerChat( AsyncPlayerChatEvent event ) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        if ( sessions.containsKey( event.getPlayer() ) ) {
            processResponse( player, event.getMessage() );
            event.setCancelled( true );
        }
    }


    /**
     * Handle sign interaction to start a dialog.
     * 
     * @param event player interaction record
     */
    @EventHandler( ignoreCancelled = true )
    public void onPlayerInteract( PlayerInteractEvent event ) {
        if ( event.getAction() != Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK )
            return;

        Block block = event.getClickedBlock();

        if ( block.getType() == Material.WALL_SIGN ) {
            // Other tests to make sure its the right sign
            startTagController( event.getPlayer() );
        }
    }


    /**
     * Trigger the start of a player's conversation. This would be called by your sign
     * interaction handler or started by a command.
     * 
     * @param player player for which conversation is to be started
     */
    public void startTagController( Player player ) {
        if ( sessions.containsKey( player ) )
            return; // Already has a controller

        PlayerSession sess = new PlayerSession();
        sess.state = TagState.PREFIX;
        sessions.put( player, sess );
        promptPlayer( player );
    }


    /**
     * Display the appropriate prompt to the player depending on what state they are currently
     * in.
     * 
     * @param player player in conversation
     */
    private void promptPlayer( Player player ) {
        String prompt = null;
        switch ( sessions.get( player ).state ) {
            case PREFIX:
                prompt = "Enter a prefix (enter 'clear' to quit)";
                break;
            case BRACKET:
                prompt = "Enter a bracket color";
                break;
            case NAME:
                prompt = "Enter a name color";
                break;
            default:
                cleanup( player );
                player.sendMessage( "Sorry some bad has happened, exiting tag manager" );
                throw new IllegalStateException( "Unknown tag state" );
        }

        player.sendMessage( prompt );
    }


    /**
     * Process chat response. Evaluate message and determine next valid state. If next state
     * is anything other than DONE, set player's current state to it and prompt them. This will
     * also reprompt player should they enter an invalid value.
     * 
     * @param player player responding
     * @param msg response message
     */
    private void processResponse( Player player, String msg ) {
        PlayerSession sess = sessions.get( player );
        sess.state = evaluateState( player, sess, msg );

        if ( sess.state == TagState.DONE || sess.state == TagState.ERR )
            cleanup( player );
        else
            promptPlayer( player );
    }


    /**
     * Evaluate the given message according to the current state.
     * 
     * @param player player in conversation
     * @param state current player state
     * @param msg response message to evaluate
     * @return next valid state; same state if invalidation errors; or ERR if terminal error.
     */
    private TagState evaluateState( Player player, PlayerSession sess, String msg ) {
        if ( "clear".equalsIgnoreCase( msg ) )
            return TagState.DONE;

        switch ( sess.state ) {
            case PREFIX:
                if ( validatePrefix( msg ) ) {
                    // Do something with valid prefix
                    sess.prefix = msg;
                    return TagState.BRACKET;
                }
                // Bark error at player, don't change state.
                return sess.state;

            case BRACKET:
                if ( validateColor( msg ) ) {
                    // Do something with valid bracket color
                    sess.bracket = msg;
                    return TagState.NAME;
                }
                // Bark error at player, don't change state.
                return sess.state;

            case NAME:
                if ( validateColor( msg ) ) {
                    // Do something with valid name color
                    sess.name = msg;
                    return TagState.DONE;
                }
                // Bark error at player, don't change state.
                return sess.state;

            default:
                player.sendMessage( "Sorry some bad has happened, exiting tag manager" );
                return TagState.ERR;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Determine if the given prefix is valid.
     * 
     * @param prefix prefix to evaluate
     * @return true if valid; false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean validatePrefix( String prefix ) {
        // Check whether prefix is valid. Return true if it is and false if not
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Determine if the given color key is valid.
     * 
     * @param color color key to evaluate
     * @return true if valid; false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean validateColor( String color ) {
        return color.matches( VALID_COLOR_PAT );
    }


    /**
     * Clean up after given player has completed or terminated conversation.
     * 
     * @param player conversation player
     */
    private void cleanup( Player player ) {
        PlayerSession sess = sessions.get( player );
        sessions.remove( player );

        if ( sess.state == TagState.DONE ) {
            player.sendMessage( "Prefix selected: " + sess.prefix );
            player.sendMessage( "Bracket color selected: " + sess.bracket );
            player.sendMessage( "Name color selected: " + sess.name );
        }
    }

    protected class PlayerSession {
        public TagState state;
        public String   prefix;
        public String   bracket;
        public String   name;
    }
}
```

## Bukkit Conversations

A rare feature of Bukkit that many do not discover unless they are pointed to it or peruse Bukkit's
source code is its `org.bukkit.conversations.ConversationFactory` resources. It is a framework,
specifically intended for what you are trying to accomplish. It has several benefits

- No need for custom control logic. Conversations can support most types of directed graphs, such
  as state machines.
- No need to maintain player storage. Conversations provide session storage for each player.
- Conversations are modal by default. All normal messages directed to a player are suppressed.
  Conversations can also be made non-modal, allowing normal messages to flow through.
- Dynamic prompt generation to allow better representation of a conversation's state.
- No need for tracking. Conversations can time out after a certain period.
- No housekeeping. Conversations free themselves up if player is logged off.

> Note the use of `sendRawMessage()` during the conversation, as it does not check conversation state
>   as `sendMessage()` does.

The following code is an implementation using Conversations. Again, this code is for educational and
demonstration purposes. Use at your own risk.

```
public class ConvoTagController implements Listener {
    private static final String       VALID_COLOR_PAT = "^[a-f0-9]$";
    private final ConversationFactory factory;


    public ConvoTagController( JavaPlugin plugin ) {
        this.factory = new ConversationFactory( plugin );
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents( this, plugin );
    }


    @EventHandler( ignoreCancelled = true )
    public void onPlayerInteract( PlayerInteractEvent event ) {
        if ( event.getAction() != Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK )
            return;

        Block block = event.getClickedBlock();

        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        if ( block.getType() == Material.WALL_SIGN ) {
            // Other tests to make sure its the right sign
            if ( !player.isConversing() )
                startConversation( player );
        }
    }


    /**
     * Trigger the start of a player's conversation. This would be called by your sign
     * interaction handler or started by a command.
     * 
     * @param player player for which conversation is to be started
     */
    private void startConversation( Player player ) {
        factory.withFirstPrompt( new PrefixPrompt() ).withPrefix( new TagPrefix() )
                .withLocalEcho( false ).withEscapeSequence( "clear" ).buildConversation( player )
                .begin();
    }

    public class TagPrefix implements ConversationPrefix {

        @Override
        public String getPrefix( ConversationContext context ) {
            return ChatColor.BLUE + "[TAGS] " + ChatColor.WHITE;
        }

    }

    public class PrefixPrompt extends ValidatingPrompt {

        @Override
        public String getPromptText( ConversationContext context ) {
            return "Enter a prefix (type 'clear' to quit)";
        }


        @Override
        protected boolean isInputValid( ConversationContext context, String input ) {
            // TODO Test to make sure prefix is valid
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        protected Prompt acceptValidatedInput( ConversationContext context, String input ) {
            context.setSessionData( "prefix", input );
            return new BracketColor();
        }
    }

    public class BracketColor extends ValidatingPrompt {

        @Override
        public String getPromptText( ConversationContext context ) {
            return "Enter a bracket color (type 'clear' to quit)";
        }


        @Override
        protected boolean isInputValid( ConversationContext context, String input ) {
            return input.matches( VALID_COLOR_PAT );
        }


        @Override
        protected Prompt acceptValidatedInput( ConversationContext context, String input ) {
            context.setSessionData( "bracket", input );
            return new NameColor();
        }

    }

    public class NameColor extends ValidatingPrompt {

        @Override
        public String getPromptText( ConversationContext context ) {
            return "Enter a name color (type 'clear' to quit)";
        }


        @Override
        protected boolean isInputValid( ConversationContext context, String input ) {
            return input.matches( VALID_COLOR_PAT );
        }


        @Override
        protected Prompt acceptValidatedInput( ConversationContext context, String input ) {
            context.setSessionData( "name", input );
            return new Done();
        }
    }

    public class Done implements Prompt {

        @Override
        public String getPromptText( ConversationContext context ) {
            Conversable c = context.getForWhom();
            String prefix = (String) context.getSessionData( "prefix" );
            String bracket = (String) context.getSessionData( "bracket" );
            String name = (String) context.getSessionData( "name" );

            c.sendRawMessage( "Prefix selected: " + prefix );
            c.sendRawMessage( "Bracket color selected: " + bracket );
            c.sendRawMessage( "Name color selected: " + name );

            if ( c instanceof Player ) {
                Player p = (Player) c;
                // Do whatever you need to do to player specifically.
            }
            return "Thank you, your settings will now take effect";
        }


        @Override
        public boolean blocksForInput( ConversationContext context ) {
            return false;
        }


        @Override
        public Prompt acceptInput( ConversationContext context, String input ) {
            return END_OF_CONVERSATION;
        }
    }
}
```